# Is it possible to find such tags from a html page paste on text area and replace its tags with another tags mentioned in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <TABLE>
        <TR>
            <TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1">
                <P CLASS="text">HR-CT</P>
            </TD>
            <TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1">
                <P CLASS="Tab-Text-7">my
                    <EM CLASS="Math-B">i</EM> Stackoverflow
                    <EM 
                    CLASS="Math-B">i</EM>
                    <EM CLASS=
                    "Math-B">i</EM>
                    <EM CLASS="Math-B">g</EM> UIP-Muster
                    <EM CLASS="Math-B">m</EM>
                </P>
            </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>
                <EM CLASS="hoch">C</EM>
                <EM CLASS="Math-C">d</EM>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Expected output:-

```
("<EM CLASS="Math-C">g</EM>", should be replaced with "&#8660;").
("<EM CLASS="Math-B">i</EM>", should be replaced with "&#126;").
```

with following code i can replace all this tags easily,but i want this to be converted into javascript code, so that it should read the data from text area and then replace all such tags with another tags.

Java Code:

```
FileInputStream fstream;
    FileOutputStream fout;
    DataInputStream in1;
    BufferedReader br;
    BufferedWriter bw=null;
    String htmlText=null;


    String line;
            fstream = new FileInputStream("D:\\Special symbol 
files\\test symbol.htm");
            String st=" ";
            fout = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Special symbol files\\test 
symbol new.html",true);
            in1 = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1,"UTF-8"));
            reader = new FileInputStream("D:\\Special symbol files\\test 
symbol.htm");           
            bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fout,"UTF-8"));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                htmlText=htmlText+line;
            }
            //htmlText=extractText(reader);
            System.out.println("html content :"+htmlText);
            System.out.println("index:"+htmlText.indexOf("<EM  
CLASS=\"Math-C\">o</EM>"));



            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-B\">i</EM>", 
"&#126;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-B\">l</EM>", 
"<EM CLASS=\"Math-B\">l</EM>");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-B\">j</EM>", 
"<EM CLASS=\"Math-B\">j</EM>");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-B\">g</EM>", 

"<EM CLASS=\"Math-B\">g</EM>");
             /*pattern = Pattern.compile("<EM CLASS=\"Math-B\">\\s*m\\s*</EM>"); 
             m = pattern.matcher(htmlText);
                htmlText=m.replaceAll("&ge;");*/
            htmlText=regExp(htmlText,"Math-B","m","&ge;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-B\">+</EM>", "&#247;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-B\">[</EM>", "&le;");

            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">o</EM>", "&#8595;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">m</EM>", "&#8593;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">u</EM>", "&#8658;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">e</EM>", "&#8658;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">t</EM>", "&#8594;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">d</EM>", "&#8594;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">r</EM>", "&#8592;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">b</EM>", "&#8592;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">w</EM>", "&#8660;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">g</EM>", "&#8660;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">s</EM>", "&#8656;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">c</EM>", "&#8656;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">n</EM>", "&#8657;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">p</EM>", "&#8659;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">v</EM>", "&#8596;");
            htmlText=htmlText.replace("<EM CLASS=\"Math-C\">f</EM>", "&#8596;");

            htmlText=htmlText.replace(">", ">\n");
            bw.write(htmlText);
            bw.close();
```

with the help of above code i can replace the tags,but i need this java code to be converted into java Script, through which data pasted to text area,can be easily replaced by clicking on button.
http://jsfiddle.net/yk6Tq/4/ (for reference)

Any one can please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is create an array of tags that you want to replace like this

```
var array = {
            '<EM CLASS="Math-C">d</EM>':'&#8660;', 
            '<EM CLASS="hoch">C</EM>':'<sup>C</sup>',
            '<EM CLASS="Math-B">g</EM>':'&#156;',
            '<EM CLASS="Math-B">i</EM>':'&#126;'
        }
```

now you can loop through the array and replace the values from your string.

```
var originalText = $('#txtArea').val();
var finalText = originalText;

for (var val in array)
   finalText = finalText.replace(new RegExp(val, "g"), array[val]);
```

here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk6Tq/11/) for the same.

Comment: Thanks sushil  I got my solution and also its working fine.

Comment: you're most welcome @poojadeshmukh. glad I was able to help you. let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Sure sushil. Really you are great,from last 4 days I was not able to code this, but you have done it, by your solution only I found my answer, and able to code it perfectly. Once again thank you soo much

Comment: This is the Solution for my question.
http://jsfiddle.net/yk6Tq/23/

with the help of this , we can find and replace multiple lines as well as same line text.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Solution for my question.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#findAndReplace').on('click', function(){

     var array = {
        '<EM CLASS="text">((\n|.*?))d</EM>':'&#8660;', 
        '<EM CLASS="data">((\n|.*?))c</EM>':'<sup>C</sup>',
        '<EM CLASS="data1">((\n|.*?))g</EM>':'&#156;',

    }

    var originalText = $('#txtArea').val();
    var finalText = originalText;

    for (var val in array)
        finalText = finalText.replace(new RegExp(val, "g"), array[val]);

    $('#txtArea').val(finalText);


  });

});
```

with the help of this , we can find and replace multiple lines as well as same line text.
Thank you @Sushil.

Comment: tumcha email id dila nahi tumhi

Comment: Hey @Sushil Hi

Can this code be used to run after uploading a html file from upload button and apply changes,as now it is applied after entering data on text area.

Comment: after uploading it will be available on the server side in the java code so you can just apply your changes in java code itself

Comment: can you explain with a demo please

Comment: i don't know java so i cannot create a demo for this. i can help you with the logic though. how do you get the uploaded file in java?? is it in stream or do you get the text in a string?

Comment: I can send you a demo, on fiddle,it is reading a image file and displaying on screen.

but html page is not applying any changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81441/discussion-between-sushil-and-pooja-deshmukh).

Comment: Hello @Sushil. Here only

Comment: Yes baghitla, but not adding properly,if there are more tables

Comment: oops sorry baghitla nh me

Comment: @Sushil I have Ping u in chat

Comment: kuthe ahaat tumhi  @poojadeshmukh?

Comment: mi mast ahe.. ata chat room pan disable zhala. how about u? how r u @poojadeshmukh ?

Comment: ho pan tumhala privileges nasel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91653/discussion-between-sushil-and-pooja-deshmukh).